# Populate multi select select2 option from REST API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, jquery-select2

I have 3 select2 fields where I want to populate them using AJAX from API. My question is, how can I populate the first select field option directly from API and then the second field option is populated also by API but  based on my selection(s) from the first select field, same goes for the third one.

For example, below are my code & data:

**API**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "project_type": "tv",
        "project_stage": "new",
        "project_name": "Project A"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "project_type": "game",
        "project_stage": "completed",
        "project_name": "Project B"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "project_type": "game",
        "project_stage": "new",
        "project_name": "Project C"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "project_stage": "completed",
        "project_type": "film",
        "project_name": "Project D"
    }
]
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="group">
        <select class="project_type" id="project_type" multiple="multiple">
                <option value=""></option>
        </select>
        <select class="project_status" id="project_status" multiple="multiple"">
                <option value=""></option>
        </select>
        <select class="project_select" id="project_select" multiple="multiple">
                <option value=""></option>
        </select>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#project_type').select2({placeholder: "Select project type",});
$('#project_status').select2({placeholder: "Select project Status",});
$('#project_select').select2({placeholder: "Select project",});
```

**Expected Result :**

Now the `project_type` select field wield populate all of the project type as option and say we select `"game"` then the `project_status` option would be :

```
<select class="project_status" id="project_status" multiple="multiple"">
    <option value="completed">Completed</option>
    <option value="new">New</option>
</select>
```

and if we select `completed`, the third filter would be:

```
<select class="project_select" id="project_select" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="Project B">Project B</option>
</select>
```

I populated this from [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/) before and its not dynamic, any help is much appreciated thanks.

**UPDATE :**

below is my current code, for odd reason even for the first filter, its not populating the option even though I'm getting the data :

```
        $('#project_type').select2({
            placeholder: "Select project type",
            ajax: {
                url: '/api/filter/',
                delay: 250,
                type: 'GET',
                data: function (params) {
                    var query = {
                      search: params.term,
                      type: 'public'
                    }
                return query
                },
                processResults: function (data) {
                    var data1 = $.map(data, function (obj, idx) {
                        console.log(obj.project_type);
                        return obj;
                    });
                    console.log("processResults2:", data1);
                    return {
                        results: data1,
                      };
                 }
            }
        });
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Here is an example of Ajax populated Select2 field: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47797831/select2-generating-id-with-ajax-response-data/47808276#47808276

Comment: I edited my question, please let me know, if theres still confusion, apologies for the misleading

Comment: Have you tried looping through the data and building your select fields from each?

Comment: Currently I'm not even able to populate the first field, its getting all the data but its not populating in the option field, I update my question with my current code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a snippet implementing Select2 Ajax populate (in cascade):

```js
var data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "project_type": "tv",
        "project_stage": "new",
        "project_name": "Project A"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "project_type": "game",
        "project_stage": "completed",
        "project_name": "Project B"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "project_type": "game",
        "project_stage": "new",
        "project_name": "Project C"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "project_stage": "completed",
        "project_type": "film",
        "project_name": "Project D"
    }
];

sel_type();
$('#project_status').select2({placeholder: ""});
$('#project_select').select2({ placeholder: ""});

function sel_type() {
  $('#project_type').select2({
      placeholder: "Select project type",
       ajax: {
       type: "POST",
       url: '/echo/json/',
       data: function(params){
         var query={
             message:params.term,
             data: data
         }
         return { json: JSON.stringify( query ) }
       },
       processResults: function (data) {
         var grouped = groupBy(data.data, 'project_type');
         var data1 = [], i = 0;
         for (var k in grouped) {
            data1.push({"id": i++, "text": k})
         }
         return {
           results: data1,
         };
      }
     }
   });
   
   $('#project_type').on('select2:select', function (e) {
      var data = e.params.data;
      console.log(data);
      sel_status(data.text);
  });
}

function sel_status(type) {
   $('#project_status').select2({
      placeholder: "Select project status",
       ajax: {
       type: "POST",
       url: '/echo/json/',
       data: function(params){
         var query={
             message:params.term,
             data: data
         }
         return { json: JSON.stringify( query ) }
       },
       processResults: function (data) {
         var data1 = $.map(data.data, function (obj, idx) {
           if (obj.project_type==type)
             return obj;
         });
         var grouped = groupBy(data1, 'project_stage');
         var data1 = [], i = 0;
         for (var k in grouped) {
            data1.push({"id": i++, "text": k})
         }
         return {
           results: data1,
         };
      }
     }
   });
   
   $('#project_status').on('select2:select', function (e) {
      var data = e.params.data;
      console.log(data);
      sel_proj(type, data.text);
  });
 }
 
 function sel_proj(type, status) {
   $('#project_select').select2({
      placeholder: "Select project",
       ajax: {
       type: "POST",
       url: '/echo/json/',
       data: function(params){
         var query={
             message:params.term,
             data: data
         }
         return { json: JSON.stringify( query ) }
       },
       processResults: function (data) {
         var data1 = $.map(data.data, function (obj, idx) {
          if (obj.project_type==type && obj.project_stage==status) {
             obj.id = obj.id || idx;
             obj.text = obj.project_name;
             return obj;
          }
         });
         return {
           results: data1,
         };
      }
     }
   });
 }
 
 var groupBy = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};
```

```css
select {
  width:200px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="group">
  <select class="project_type" id="project_type" multiple="multiple">
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <select class="project_status" id="project_status" multiple="multiple">
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <select class="project_select" id="project_select" multiple="multiple">
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

but because of the Ajax request it does not work here in StackOverflow.

A working version (using JsFiddle echo) is here: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/4nq62nqo/

P.S.: you have to change the uri in Ajax request to yours, and remove POST of data.

Comment: Hi, @beaver Thanks you so much for your help! this is quite the code! but I realize a small bug where if you multi select the field its only update the next select field with the latest selected option in the first field,  I'm trying myself right now, but would appreciate it enormously if you can help me with it, again, thanks!

Comment: I updated my jsfiddle, probably it is not yet as desired, but it's a good point. You can do a bit more work to complete/edit the code!

Comment: yes of course, I'm actually doing it inside my project, but thanks again for you help, this is more than enough